# Kinetic energy in center of mass frame of a system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, momentum

[image]

This appears in an Olympiad handout by Kevin Zhou. However I don't get where this result came at all. How would you prove it?
I also don't see in what situations the right side of the expression can be more useful than the left side.